# Redirect User From Browser to My App after open a specific URL

Tags: android, payment, intentfilter

I wrote an application that user after click on buy Button He/She redirect to Internet Browser (e.g: chrome) and after payment I want he come back to my App (my activity) so I found out that I should use Intent-Filter but It doesn't work for me!

I add these codes in manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="returnApp" android:scheme="myapp"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

And when I open a url like this:

> myapp://returnApp?status=1

my app doesn't open.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to open it like `myapp://returnApp/?status=1` (add trailing slash character).
This is happens because [path](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path) parameter is defined with default value of `/`.

Unfortunately, you can't match exactly for empty string. As documentation states:

> The path part of a URI which must begin with a /.

If you are really need to start app with exactly url `myapp://returnApp?status=1` you can add  `android:pathPattern=".*"` parameter to your data clause like

```
<intent-filter>
    ...
    <data android:host="returnApp" android:scheme="myapp" android:pathPattern=".*"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Intent filter with data `android:pathPattern=".*"` will match for any paths including empty one.

Comment: @esmaeil , did you tried to launch the app from command line? What is being printed in logcat when you execute following command in command line shell `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'myapp://returnApp?status=1' --debug-log-resolution` ?

Comment: Hello @pepyakin when I am opening it from shell it is wroking fine but when ! open it from web page in browser it didn't works can you please tell me the problem.

Comment: @rana_sadam can u show me your intent-filter, shell command and link which u use to open app from the web page?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same!. Code Please

Comment: Please share the code if you have fixed this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `android:pathPattern=".*"` this worked like butter. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

1. open the firebase app
2. click on a dynamic link
3. create your own redirect call back link on firebase like https://example.page.link/payment

[image: Check firebase image setup]

4. setup link on your manifest.xml file like following code

```html
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:autoVerify="true">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="example.page.link" android:path="/payment"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="example.page.link" android:path="/payment"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

5. run your app
6. check the firebase link on android phone browser
7. it's work yup