# Check if android app is installed from web page browser

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, applinks

I have an Android app and I'm building a corresponding website. I would like to write a code in my website home page "index.php" which check if my app is installed direct the user to thanks page url ,
 or if the app isn't installed redirect user to download page

Does someone know how to implement this procedure?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect User From Browser to My App after open a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870983/redirect-user-from-browser-to-my-app-after-open-a-specific-url)

Comment: No, this wasn't that duplicate. Here, he wants to check in the browser without clicking on any URLs or without redirecting from website to installed app.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do if the user has accessed your webpage from Chrome browser(Chrome 59+).

You need to create the Webapp manifest for your website and configure your app's package name. Now from your website, you can check whether your app is installed or not.

You can find the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/getinstalledrelatedapps).